# One Login page that allows three Roles in but denies Unauthorized Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Having a problem with my C# application and some help would be greatly appreciated.

Creating a project with C# and I've been stuck on trying to get Users who are not authorized by the Administrator to not be able to login.

This is is my Account Controller. I want to start off by just having Admins going into the application and anyone else going to a View or have an Error Message displayed.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                WebSecurity.Logout();
                return View("RegisterAuthorisation");

            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
   }
```

It just isn't working as everyone just gets through to the page located in the Else statement. My database is fine and I've implemented code in the HTML which prevents Users other than Admins access to everything.

As I said I would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: Else statement to return View("RegisterAuthorisation"); or to  ModelState.AddModelError

Comment: @adopilot nah doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You might not have initialized the roles manager. Add an attribute `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` to the accounts controller. This ensures that the user's data is retrieved from the database when authenticated. You might want to initialize this globally via RegisterGlobalFilters if your users could log into your application from other controllers. Take a look at [this MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/08/15/initializesimplemembership-attribute-and-simplemembership-exceptions/).